# Splitting a string with brackets using regular expression in python

Tags: python, regex

Suppose I have a string like `str = "[Hi all], [this is] [an example] "`. I want to split it into several pieces, each of which consists content inside a pair bracket. In another word, i want to grab the phrases inside each pair of bracket. The result should be like:

```
['Hi all', 'this is', 'an example']
```

How can I achieve this goal using a regular expression in Python?

Comment: you don't want to split, but need to filter-out (means find all) all strings between `[` `]`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
data = "[Hi all], [this is] [an example] "
import re
print re.findall("\[(.*?)\]", data)    # ['Hi all', 'this is', 'an example']
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/qiG6j-36Tv9nyv4G)

Comment: Yes: `\[(.*?)\]` works (+1) but: `\[([^[\]]*)\]` is more efficient and precise.

Comment: @ridgerunner Thanks :) But how do we check which of them is efficient?

Comment: The efficiency of any given regex/target string combination is best measured directly by benchmarking. However, the book: [Mastering Regular Expressions (3rd Edition)](http://www.amazon.com/Mastering-Regular-Expressions-Jeffrey-Friedl/dp/0596528124 "By Jeffrey Friedl. Best book on Regex - ever!") provides an in-depth look at precisely how a regex engine goes about its job and culminates with a chapter describing how to write an efficient regex. Once this book is digested, one will never look at a dot-star in the same way again. The book discusses benchmarking as well.

Comment: Long story short, with the `\[(.*?)\]` lazy-dot-star expression the regex engine must backtrack on each and every character, whereas the `\[([^[\]]*)\]` expression matches the entire contents between the brackets in one gulp (and no backtracking). Note also that some regex engines (e.g. Perl) have optimized code that very efficiently handles lazy quantifiers and in this case, your expression may actually be faster. But only benchmarking will tell for sure.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
import re
str = "[Hi all], [this is] [an example] "
contents = re.findall('\[(.*?)\]', str)
```

Answer (score 2):

I've run into this problem a few times - Regular expressions will work unless you have nested brackets.  In the more general case where you might have nested brackets, the following will work:

```
def bracketed_split(string, delimiter, strip_brackets=False):
    """ Split a string by the delimiter unless it is inside brackets.
    e.g.
        list(bracketed_split('abc,(def,ghi),jkl', delimiter=',')) == ['abc', '(def,ghi)', 'jkl']
    """

    openers = '[{(<'
    closers = ']})>'
    opener_to_closer = dict(zip(openers, closers))
    opening_bracket = dict()
    current_string = ''
    depth = 0
    for c in string:
        if c in openers:
            depth += 1
            opening_bracket[depth] = c
            if strip_brackets and depth == 1:
                continue
        elif c in closers:
            assert depth > 0, f"You exited more brackets that we have entered in string {string}"
            assert c == opener_to_closer[opening_bracket[depth]], f"Closing bracket {c} did not match opening bracket {opening_bracket[depth]} in string {string}"
            depth -= 1
            if strip_brackets and depth == 0:
                continue
        if depth == 0 and c == delimiter:
            yield current_string
            current_string = ''
        else:
            current_string += c
    assert depth == 0, f'You did not close all brackets in string {string}'
    yield current_string
```

```
>>> list(bracketed_split("[Hi all], [this is] [an example]", delimiter=' '))
['[Hi all],', '[this is]', '[an example]']

>>> list(bracketed_split("[Hi all], [this is] [a [nested] example]", delimiter=' '))
['[Hi all],', '[this is]', '[a [nested] example]']
```